# Adding text to a specific TableLayoutPanel cell and than make an image from the table

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, tablelayoutpanel

I want to add some text in certain cells that I select.
In order to do that, I add in that `TableLayoutPanel` cell a `RichTextBox`.
 When I want to add a photo in a `TableLayoutPanel` cell, I add a `PictureBox`.

The problem is when I save the image from the entire table.
In that image the `RichTextBox` controls are disappearing.

Here is the code that I use to make the image from the `TableLayoutPanel`:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(tableLayoutPanel1.Width, tableLayoutPanel1.Height);
tableLayoutPanel1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, tableLayoutPanel1.Width, 
                                                       tableLayoutPanel1.Height));
bm.Save(path);
```

Comment: That's a *feature* of the `RichTextBox` control. It's text content will not be rendered using the `Control.DrawToBitmap()` method. If you want to include the RTB text, you'll have to take a Screenshot of the `TableLayouPanel` portion.

Comment: Google "c# richtextbox drawtobitmap", lots of hits.